# If a function f is differentiable then its derivate is Borel measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I need help solving this interesting result:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable. Prove that $f'$ Borel measurable.

I tried to start with, if $f$ is differentiable then $f'(x)$ exists for all $x∈ \mathbb{R}$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: $f'$ is a limit of measurable functions.

Answer (score 5):

$f'$ is the pointwise limit of the sequence:

$$f_n(x) = \frac{f(x+1/n) - f(x)}{1/n}$$

Comment: Thank you, but how do you prove that $f_n(x)$ is measurable? And with that you have proved that $f'$ is measurable but not Borel measurable...

Comment: @JennaTaylor the composition of Borel functions is a Borel function, this justifies that $f_n$ is Borel. Now the pointwise limit of Borel functions is also Borel.

Comment: Yes, the composition of Borel measurable functions is Borel measurable. But how do you prove that each $f_n$ is Borel measurable? That is what I got left...

Answer (score 1):

You could also say that:
f=differentiable => f=continuous.
Since f=differentiable => $\exists$f '(x) = $\lim_{h\to 0}$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ =>  f '(x) = lim$_n$$\frac{f(x+1/n)-f(x)}{1/n}$.

Then from Heine's deffinition (?)* $\forall$(x$_n$)$_n$$\in$$\mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon$>0: x$_n$ $\rightarrow$ x$_0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\sigma$(f(x$_n$),f(x)) < $\epsilon$.

Suppose f$_n$(x) = $\frac{f(x+1/n)-f(x)}{1/n}$, f=continuous (so f(x+1/n)=continuous $\forall$n). Therefore so far we have: $\forall$x>0 and $\forall$$\epsilon$>0 $\exists$n$_0$$\in$$\mathbb{N}$ so that as n$\geq$n$_0$ then $\sigma$(f(x$_n$),f(x)) < $\epsilon$ $\Rightarrow$  (f$_n$)$_n$ $\rightarrow$ f p.w.

Then f=*Baire-1* => f=Borel-meas. (this because f=lim$_n$f$_n$ $\Rightarrow$ f=limsup$_n$f$_n$, for (f$_n$)$_n$ = seqeuence of meassurable functions)

*I dont know how it is called in English. In Measure Theory or Real Analysis we call it in Greek "Arxi/Archi tis Metaforas" (= principle of transport).

PS: I'm an undergraduate student (mathematics), therefore there may be many mistakes (in english and in mathematical structure)
I hope i helped.

Comment: What you call "Archi tis Metaforas" is called "Sequential Criteria" in English texts.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that!